# React: Passing value to a functional component results in undefined value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass values one by one to a functional component from array.map function. Unfortunately the component is not redering the value.

[image]

This is what I'm getting. There are room names stored in DB that should be printed here.

Homescreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Room from "../components/Room";

export default function Homescreen() {
  const [rooms, setRooms] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const data = (await axios.get("/api/rooms/getallrooms")).data;
      setRooms(data);
      setLoading(false);
      setError(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(true);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      ) : error ? (
        <h1>Error fetching details from API</h1>
      ) : (
        rooms.map((room) => {
          return (<div>
              <Room key={room._id} room={room}></Room>
          </div>
        )
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Room.js (Funcitonal component that should print room names):

```
import React from "react";

function Room(room){
    console.log(room.name)
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Room name: {room.name}.</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Room;
```

The data is fetched correctly from db because if, instead of passing the value to component I print directly into my main screen, the values are printed.

In otherwords, in Homescreen.js, doing <p>{room.name}</p> instead of <Room key={room._id} room={room}></Room> print room names correctly.

So I reckon the problem is coming when I'm passing the values as props.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: {room.room.name}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter passed to a [function component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) is the `props` object which contains the passed props, so you just need to grab `props.room` from there:

```
function Room(props){
    console.log(props.room.name)
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Room name: {props.room.name}.</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Or, with [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring):

```
function Room({ room }){
    console.log(room.name)
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Room name: {room.name}.</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I seem to have mixed the concept of destructuring with props object. Thanks it worked!